# I would like to implement a rejection handler code that exits the procedure after 10 rejection

Tags: node.js

I made a rejection handler, in this rejection handler I run my function `run()`.

However this can be generated in a loop. Is it can pose a serious problem in the use of my code so I want to implement if the code returns 10 rejection then it quits the procedure here is an example of what I did

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason);
  run();
});

if(process.on('unhandledRejection', == 10 , (reason, p)  => {
  process.exit();
}
```

Comment: why not just use a global counter variable?

Comment: this would allow to quit the procedure after 10 errors if yes you could show me an example it would be nice please ?

Comment: you don't know how to define a variable, increase it, and check whether it is greater than 10? If no, then I would recommend doing a tutorial on javascript first.